# "unlock to activate" Apple Watch Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I am using openParentApplication:reply: method to communicate to iPhone using Apple Watch.
everything goes fine except that if i lock the iPhone Simulator a message appears on Watch simulator "**unlock to activate**" where i cannot press the button on watch app to send the message to iPhone

i've had the same issue using the iPhone simulator on iPhone 6 iOS 8.3 as well as iOS 8.2 (different betas of xcode)

notice that iOS 8.2 beta 3 release note mentions the following:

(WKInterfaceController methods: openParentApplication:reply: **now** launches the containing app in the background when the iPhone (or iOS Simulator) is unlocked or locked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pretty good answer I saw while searching for the same thing :)

[WatchKit app "Unlock to activate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156127/watchkit-app-unlock-to-activate/29163799#29163799)

Comment: so it's very clear now that this is just a test function in simulator. The app on real watch would not be locked after iphone locked.